# Ruby: unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

Very new to Ruby, unable to see the titular syntax error in this bit of code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby                                                               

require 'sensu-plugin/metric/cli'                                                  

class MetricAvailableUpdates < Sensu::Plugin::Metric::CLI::Graphite                

  option :scheme,                                                                  
    description: 'Metric naming scheme',                                           
    long: '--scheme SCHEME',                                                       
    short: '-s SCHEME',                                                            
    default: "#{Socket.gethostname}"                                               

  def run                                                                          
    # Get the metrics.                                                             
    output = %x[/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable]               
    output_lines = output.split(/(\n)/)                                            

    metrics = {}                                                                   

    updates_pattern = " packages can be updated."                                  
    updates = output_lines[0].tr(upgrades_pattern, "").to_i                        
    metrics[:available_updates] = updates                                          

    security_updates_pattern = " updates are security updates."                    
    security_updates = output_lines[2].tr(security_updates_pattern, "").to_i       
    metrics[:available_security_updates] = security_updates                        

    # Print them in graphite format.                                               
    metrics.each do |k, v|                                                         
      output [config[:scheme], k].join('.'), v                                     
    end                                                                            

    # Done                                                                         
    ok                                                                             
  end                                                                              

end
```

I can add the code that precedes this if the syntax error is in fact before this section. **Edit: added complete file contents per comment request**

The complete error, in case that is useful:

```
./metrics-available-updates.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
      output [config[:scheme], k].join('.'), v
```

Comment: What's `output`?

Comment: It is a method of the parent class. In case the details help, you can see `output` here: https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugin/blob/master/lib/sensu-plugin/metric/cli.rb I am inheriting from `Graphite`, so it is the method starting on line 21.

Comment: There are no syntax errors in this concrete snippet. Show the whole file.

Comment: Added complete file contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you play around a bit, you will notice that the syntax error goes away either when you comment out the offending line, **or alternatively** the line

```
output = %x[/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable]
```

When Ruby parses a file, it needs to guess, whether a symbol denotes a method call, or a variable reference. In this case, `output` springs into existence as a variable, but further down, you write

```
output [config[:scheme], k].join('.'), v
```

which means it suddenly becomes a method call.

I admit that the Ruby lexer should give a more helpful error message....

Comment: Argh, that earlier `output` is what did it (sort of)! I had commented out the offending line and knew it had something to do with that, but I wasn't sure. And that explains the difference between my code and the mongo sample I mentioned in my comment on the previous answer. I was merging an old piece of code with the plugin "framework", and I hadn't noticed they both used the name `output` for different things. I come from Python, and I do think Ruby tends to give very cryptic messages. I'm sure I'll grow to appreciate Ruby's strengths in time thought.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `parentheses`

```
...
metrics.each do |k, v|                                                         
  output([config[:scheme], k].join('.'), v)
end
...
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot in the morning when I am back at the machine with this code. I find this answer interesting, because I lifted this `each..do` loop from  a functioning piece of code, located here: https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-mongodb/blob/master/bin/metrics-mongodb.rb, which you'll notice on line 120 is using the exact same loop as what I have implemented in my code. If your solution works, I'll be curious why you can go without parenthesis in one, but not the other.